# Will changing applicationHost.config cause IIS7 restart?

Tags: iis, iis-7, configuration

If I make a change to the file:

%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

and update it with a change resulting in a valid config, will it cause IIS7 to restart and force restarts on all the apps?

I am trying this out with a hot-cloned vm of the server, but like to know if anyone has experience of either of these scenarios, what the expected outcome should be.

Many thanks

Comment: Well, getting the format of the configuration file wrong does indeed break the server.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I put together [a short video](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2011/03/19/asp-net-appdomain-what-it-is-and-why-it-s-important-part-12-of-52-part-series.aspx) on this just last week.  It covers the differences between AppDomains and AppPools and what causes recycles.  I walk through various setting changes that cause full recycles and AppDomain recycles.  I also cover how you can tell if a recycle occurs and what the impact is.

The short answer is that it depends. 'Touching' applicationHost.config by itself won't cause any level of recycle, but certain config changes will.  *Any* change to .NET's machine.config or root web.config will cause an AppDomain recycle on the server for that framework version.  Any change to a site's web.config will cause an AppDomain recycle for that site.

Comment: Excellent video and explanation.

Answer (score 3):

If you edit App Pool properties, the App Pools should recycle (by default, unless disallowrotationonconfigchange is set, or its modern-day equivalent).

Otherwise, no, any system.webServer changes I can think of will not cause a restart of the app pools.

However, modifying web.config values may cause the apps to restart (the AppDomains) if you're using .Net.

See also: http://forums.asp.net/p/1344814/2742551.aspx

Comment: +1 for a pretty much dead on answer.  One comment is that touching web.config will *always* cause an app domain recycle.

Comment: does this mean i could add a host header without triggering a restart?

Comment: @mcintyre321 Correct. A host header change won't cause an AppDomain recycle.

Comment: Changing the global rewrite rules in applicationHost -> configuration -> rewrite seems to cause all the app pools to recycle though it's not clear why that would happen.  For clarity, I haven't tested whether they are actually recycled or whether there is just a temporary interruption to their connection.  Anyone know for sure? @ScottForsyth-MVP ?

Comment: @RichardHauer At some point URL Rewrite started causing appdomain recycles at the server level too. I noticed the shift a few years ago but I haven't track down when it switched. Originally that didn't occur with rule changes at the global level. So that is a bummer when it comes to making changes to global rewrite rules. They now do cause an app domain recycle on all sites.

Comment: @ScottForsyth-MVP This is one of the reasons I have avoided the rules engine in favour of Helicon APE for such a long time... :(

Comment: It's too bad because URL Rewrite is so elegant and powerful. But you're right that the appdomain restart doesn't work well for frequent rule changes.